# Elastic DSL query for dynamic fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I need help to build Elastic query that skip records where `channelMessage.channelMessageType` equal `RESUME_EXECUTION`
AND
`replyMessages` array is empty or first element `channelMessageType` equal `INTENT_FINISHED`.

in summery like:

```
(channelMessage.channelMessageType equal 'RESUME_EXECUTION' AND (replyMessages is empty or first element .'channelMessageType' equal 'INTENT_FINISHED'))
```

**mapping info for query fields**:

```
    "channelMessage": {
                    "dynamic": "true",
                    "properties": {
                        "channelMessageType": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "store": true,
                            "fielddata": true
                        },...

     "replyMessages": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "dynamic": "true",
                    "properties": {
                        "channelMessageType": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "store": true,
                            "fielddata": true
                        },...
```

what i tried so far:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must_not" : [
      {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "term" : {
                "channelMessage.channelMessageType" : {
                  "value" : "RESUME_EXECUTION",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not" : [
            {
              "exists" : {
                "field" : "replyMessages.channelMessageType",
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "term" : {
                "channelMessage.channelMessageType" : {
                  "value" : "RESUME_EXECUTION",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "script" : {
                "script" : {
                  "source" : "doc['replyMessages.channelMessageType'].length == 1",
                  "lang" : "painless"
                },
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            },
            {
              "term" : {
                "replyMessages.channelMessageType" : {
                  "value" : "INTENT_FINISHED",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While reading more elastics docs, i found the following [warning](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html):

```
Avoid using the term query for text fields.
By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of text fields as part of analysis. This can make finding exact matches for text field values difficult.
To search text field values, use the match query instead.
```

and by checking the index mapping types, `channelMessage.channelMessageType` was `text` which was the reason why the query does not work.
and by replacing all `term` with `match` operators my issue solved!